# How to convert this for loop into for each

Tags: java, for-loop

I'm teaching myself how to code. 
This is an exercise from a book.
I was able to write the for loop in no time.
Why am I having a hard time converting this for loop into a for each.
What am i missing or doing wrong. Thanks.

```
/**
 * Exercise 4.75 
 * Add a method busiestHour to LogAnalyzer that returns the busiest hour
 * You can do this by looking into the hour counts array to find the element
 * with the biggest count.
 * Hint: Do you need to check every element to see if you have found the busiest
 * hour? If so, use a for loop or a for-each loop. Which one is better in this case.
 */

public int busiestHour(){
    int max = hourCounts[0];
    int counter = 0;
    for(int index = 0; index < hourCounts.length; index++){
        if(max < hourCounts[index]){
            max = hourCounts[index];
            counter = index; 
        }
    }
    return counter;
}

/**
 * for each version my attempt
 */
public int busiestHour2()
{
   int max = hourCounts[0];
   int counter = 0;
   for(int index : hourCounts){
       if(max < hourCounts[index]){ 
          max = hourCounts[index];
          counter = index;          
       }
    }
   return counter;
}
```

Comment: Oh, sorry about that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already said, the `for each` statements iterate over a list or an array of elements providing the next **element** in the sequence. The `for` statements provide an **iterator** for the list or array and let the programmer  decide how to use that iterator.

For your case, the correct `for each` statements should be:

```
public int busiestHour2()
{
   int max = hourCounts[0];
   int counter = 0;
   int index = 0;
   for(int hourCount : hourCounts){
       if(max < hourCount){ 
          max = hourCount;
          counter = index;          
       }
       index = index + 1;
    }
   return counter;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for-each iterates over the elements and you work with the element, not the index. So in `for(int index : hourCounts){` your `index` is actually already the current element in `hourCounts`. In other words you have the count of the current hour. If you for example iterate over an String array, then the variable declaration in that for-each loop would be of type String, not int. This also means you don't have access to the index at all, unless you do that yourself.

I won't show a solution (it would be ugly too) for this problem, but I think the purpose of this exercise is to show you the limits of for-each and where the classic for-loop has still it's justification.